# Adding additional fields based on user interaction to create a post

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, django-models

How can I add an additional field via a user click, So the end result I want is to have a create page with buttons saying add paragraph ,add image, add subtitle etc. Im using Python/Django along with Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For backend storage you can try:

```
from django.db import models

class Paragraph(models.Model):
paragraph = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
   return self.paragraph

class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=some/path)

def __str__(self):
   return self.image


class Page(models.Model):
paragraph = models.ManyToManyField(Paragraph)
image = models.ManyToManyField(Image)


def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

Hope it helps,